# What part of the Javascript do i edit?

Tags: javascript

I found this great tutorial http://bavotasan.com/2009/creating-a-jquery-mouseover-fade-effect/

Its easy to follow but i am getting stuck with the JS because i want to have more than one image on the page.

Can someone assist.

Comment: we sure could. What is your code, how is it implemented and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Do you want to have this roll over effect on all images on the page, or just specific ones? Also, get the community a working example using http://jsfiddle.net/ that we can play around with.

Comment: Hello, i'm using the code set out in the tutorial, nothing is live yet. I need to have 6 images with hat effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to `edit` your `script` (May be the `selector`).But you have to set two `classes` for each of your `images`, one is for `common identity` (will be feasible while selecting from `Jquery`) and the other one is to set `unique styles` to each pair of your `images`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LhaEb/)

Comment: Thanks this is a big help, it has answered my question.